# unable to clear the text of dropdown

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am unable to clear the selected text in the dropdown and I am using a bootstrap multi-select plugin. I have used empty, reset and destroy, but I am unable to clear the selected text but it is clearing the selected dropdown values.

This is my div:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 form-group input search-box" style="padding-left:0">
    <div class="input-group event-search" id="reset">
        @Html.DropDownList("EventCategoryDDL", @ViewBag.EventCategories as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control call-checkbox", @multiple = "multiple" })
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

$('#btnReset').click(function () {
   $('#EventCategoryDDL').multiselect('refresh');
   oTable.columns().search('').draw();
}

$("#EventCategoryDDL").multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    nonSelectedText: '-- Select Category --'
});
```

I have tried a lot of possibilities but I am unable to clear the selected text from dropdown. I used multi-select refresh, but it is refreshing the dropdown values but it is not clearing the selected text of dropdown.

Comment: do you have an option to change the control of dropdown?

Comment: i don't have an option to the control of dropdown @Jeric Cruz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
$('#btnReset').click(function () {
        $("#EventCategoryDDL option").removeAttr('selected').prop('selected', false);
        $('#EventCategoryDDL').multiselect('refresh');
}
```

Comment: it is removing seleted checkboxes in the dropdown but i need to clear the text which display in the box after checkbox values selected

Comment: So, for that you can try this `$("#EventCategoryDDL").val("")`.

Comment: $("#EventCategoryDDL").val("") ---- this is also clearing dropdown values but it is also not clearing the selected text which displays

Comment: By clearing do you mean removing the selected items from the list?

Comment: Check the updated answer. It will work at your end too.